# Tomcat 7 abnormal end

Tags: tomcat, solr, crash, tomcat7

Today my tomcat7 had an abnormal end and in want to know why because we are getting close to the point where our system will get productive. I want to know why this error happens to prevent them in the future.

This is what i get from my catalina.2013-12-13.log.

```
13.12.2013 10:56:45 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
13.12.2013 10:56:45 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
13.12.2013 10:56:45 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/solr] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ThreadLocalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ThreadLocalDateFormat@2429e843]) and a value of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat@6b2ed43a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13.12.2013 10:56:45 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/solr] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ThreadLocalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ThreadLocalDateFormat@2429e843]) and a value of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat@6b2ed43a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13.12.2013 10:56:45 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/solr] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ThreadLocalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ThreadLocalDateFormat@2429e843]) and a value of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat@6b2ed43a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13.12.2013 10:56:45 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/solr] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ThreadLocalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ThreadLocalDateFormat@2429e843]) and a value of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat@6b2ed43a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13.12.2013 10:56:45 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/solr] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ThreadLocalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ThreadLocalDateFormat@2429e843]) and a value of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat@6b2ed43a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13.12.2013 10:56:45 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/solr] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ThreadLocalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ThreadLocalDateFormat@2429e843]) and a value of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat@6b2ed43a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13.12.2013 10:56:45 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/solr] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ThreadLocalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ThreadLocalDateFormat@2429e843]) and a value of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat@6b2ed43a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13.12.2013 10:56:45 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/solr] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ThreadLocalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ThreadLocalDateFormat@2429e843]) and a value of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat@6b2ed43a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13.12.2013 10:56:45 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/solr] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ThreadLocalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ThreadLocalDateFormat@2429e843]) and a value of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat@6b2ed43a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13.12.2013 10:56:45 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/solr] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ThreadLocalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ThreadLocalDateFormat@2429e843]) and a value of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat@6b2ed43a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
13.12.2013 10:56:45 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
13.12.2013 10:56:45 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
13.12.2013 10:56:47 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
13.12.2013 10:56:47 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 407 ms
13.12.2013 10:56:47 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
13.12.2013 10:56:47 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
13.12.2013 10:56:47 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml
13.12.2013 10:56:47 org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
```

Has anybody of you ever seen such a error? What could cause this one?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did this log entry come out of the blue or when you stopped the tomcat?

Comment: Out of the blue. The tomcat stops because of this.

Comment: Did you figured out what as causing this? And how did you fixed it?

Comment: No. Iam currently changing to elasticsearch which in my opinion is the better choice right now.